# Android DJI SDK creating massive log files

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Is there a way to disable creating massive log files with the DJI android SDK? There doesn't seem to be any detail in the documentation. Looking at the cache on a device I see massive base64 encoded log files which you can see in the picture below. I assume they are related to fly zones -> class - **FlyZoneManager** (I'm going based on the NFZ folder name) which I added to my app. Some files are multiple GB in size and filling up a device.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I worked quite a lot with DJI Mobile SDK so far and I never payed attention to the DJI folder itself as I wrote my own logs in my own folder structure.

So after seeing your screenshot I first thought: WTH!? Why is DJI saving so many files, logs etc. on it's own without even telling you?

`DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLDMManager().enableLDM();` is your friend I guess to at least make sure this data is not sent over the internet somewhere.

To come back to your question: I currently see no possibility to directly disable this. However you can try enabling the LDM as shown above and hopefully disable the behaviour of downloading updates to NFZ in order to reduce the space occupied.

What I find really suspicious is the fact that ALL these files are either binary and/or base64 encoded, so the developer/user has no information on what kind of information is saved and where the information might be sent to...

Comment: Thanks that's really good to know and useful especially when a user is running on a data plan. I logged an issue on github and they opened a ticket so I guess I'll see what they say. Yeah its crazy how much data is stored, along with those concerns, on older smaller capacity phones we test with I keep having to clear these folders. Even after uninstalling the app!

Answer (score 1):

NFZ actually means "no fly zones" geo-fencing; they call it "fly save". [Patching the firmware](https://nolimitdronez.com) lets one fly anywhere (which might cause trouble), but also should disable these log files. I'd rather suggest to keep only the current one, alike common log-file rotation does.